# MVC Drop Down list with entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I've created an MVC project using entity framework code first.  My model is simply a form that gathers information.

```
public class Application
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleInitial { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int SSN { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State {get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public int HomePhone { get; set; }
    public int BusinessPhone { get; set; }
    public int MobilePhone { get; set; }
```

}

My goal is to create a drop down list with all of the states, but I'm finding this to be very difficult given that I've already created the database via scaffolding with views and controllers.  Is there a simple way to do this and tie it in with the existing database?  I've searched for almost the entire day with no luck.  An overview/explanation of what to include for the model/controller/view would be amazing!

---

Update: I've created a new model named "State" with properties "Id" and "StateName" and have created some states in the database. In my "Application" controller inside the Create action method I have:

***Controller***

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {

        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        this.ViewData["Id"] = new SelectList(db.States.ToList(), "Id", "StateName");
        return View();
    }
```

*View*

```
@Html.DropDownList("Id")
```

Now the problem is I'm getting this error " There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Id'." Would really appreciate help!

Comment: what is the question, how to extract data from db, or show on UI?

Comment: Well I'm not sure exactly how to go about it. I currently have an application table (above). Do I need to create another table named "States" manually in the designer or with code first?  After that I would need to know how to extract the data and then show it on my existing form.

Comment: check some tutorials http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: I've already created the form via scaffolding and have an existing database with the application information.  My question is how to create a drop down list and add it to my existing form.

Comment: You need to have a database table (or some other data storage) that holds the available states. You then get them, assign them to a `SelectList` and use `@Html.DropDownFor()` to select and assign one to  your `State` property.

Comment: Thanks Stephen this makes sense but I'm not exactly sure how to implement your suggestion. I've created a new table via the visual studio designer called "States" with "Id" and "StateName" columns and have the state names stored. Not sure what to do next?

Comment: Now you have a relationship between `Application` and States` so the `State` property should be `int`. You should be using a view model, but to get you started, in the controller `ViewBag.States = new SelectList(db.States.ToList(), "Id", "StateName");` and in the view `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State, (SelectList)ViewBag.States)`.

Comment: @dc922 did you manage to achieve this ?

Answer (score 10):

Its quite simple. Add an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property to your model(Here I suggest you make a ViewModel that can have the exact same properties as `Application` with the below code included as a property). Then you just need to build the list and send it to your view

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> States{ get; set; }
```

I will assume you want to retrieve the `State` values from the db. Here is how you will do it:

```
private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetAllStates()
{
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> list = from s in db.Applications
                                       select new SelectListItem
                                       {
                                           Selected = false,
                                           Text = s.State,
                                           Value = s.State
                                       };
    return list;
}
```

Or this...

```
private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetAllStates()
{
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> list = db.Applications.Select(s => new SelectListItem
                                       {
                                           Selected = false,
                                           Text = s.State,
                                           Value = s.State
                                       });

    return list;
}
```

Then do something like this in your action:

```
var app = new Application
{
    States = GetAllStates()
};

return View(app);
```

Then finally, use Razor on the view to display the Dropdown list like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State, Model.States, "--Select a State--")
```

The 1st parameter is the property of the model to update, the 2nd is the list of data, and 3rd is the default message that will be displayed

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works great!  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a data layer that retrieves a list of what you want. Then use EF to get all the states.

```
//assuming you have a table of states..
var states = db.States();
```

The states table should be a Unique list of states.

```
var selectList = new List<SelectListItem>(); 

foreach (var thing in states)
{
    //if you got everything, thus the ID field for the value...   
   selectList.Add(new SelectListItem 
                      {
                           Text = thing.State, 
                           Selected = false, 
                           Value = thing.ID
                      });
}
```

Make sure in your view model class that selectlist is a public property.....and set to what you did above. You also need to provide a string for the view selection post back.

```
StatesSelectList = selectList;
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StatesSelectList { get; set; }
public string SelectedState { get; set; }
```

In your view, do this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(p => Model.SelectedState, Model.StatesSelectList)
```

Comment: And what happens when you create the very first `Application`? `application.select(p=>p.State)` would be empty and you would never be able to add a new `Application`!

Comment: The very first statement of my answer is that the data layer must be accessed.  If there is nothing in the application list it's up to the data layer to populate it.  Certainly the op is using a database right?  If not then the data layer must determine a way to provide the first set of information.  This is a common pattern in MVC (the initialization of the model)... It is realized when a controller creates an instance of the model and passes it back to the view.

Comment: Work through your logic again. Hint: a separate table is required for  states :)

Comment: I didn't show op init logic, you're right. I probably confused him by showing a View Model implementation and moving everything to VM anyway. The example, also attempts to show separating Data Access Layers, (The third block of code could be move to repository class). But you are right the VM must populate everything (in the null CTOR) for the view to work properly..

Comment: I still don't think your getting it. An `Application` object has a `State` property. In order to create an `Application` and save it to the database you need to select a `State`. You are querying the `Application` table to get the states. If no `Application`s have yet been created, then the collection of states is empty so you cant assign a state so therefore you cant save it. Its a Catch 22! Just edit your answer it indicate a separate `States` table is required and that you create the dropdown from the `States` table, not the `Application` table

Comment: Ok I understand where you're headed now.  In the example above, the very first line assumed there was already a collection of application objects, I was showing him how to pull from there.  I'll update answer.

Comment: Dude, all I showed in the logic above was how to use a backend database to populate a Drop Down List, I assume the person coding the solution would know when to implement it and tweak to make it work.  Oh by the way DropDownBoxes can have a selected default entry, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple Code step by step

1) In Entity Framework Class

```
var productsList = (from product in dbContext.Products
                     select new ProductDTO
                     {
                       ProductId = product.ProductId,
                       ProductName = product.ProductName,
                       }).ToList();
```

2) In Controller

```
ViewBag.productsList = new EntityFrameWorkClass().GetBusinessSubCategoriesListForDD();
```

3) In View

```
@Html.DropDownList("Product_ProductId", new SelectList(ViewBag.productsList, "ProductId", "ProductName"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

OR

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Product_ProductId, new SelectList(ViewBag.productsList , "ProductId", "ProductName"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is a States model that has a Id and a StateName property.

Change to the list to ViewData["State"] to ensure easy binding on POST.

Id is the value that will be sent in the POST data ie.. State = Id.  The StateName is what will be displayed in the Select list.  **So for your model this is not correct as State is a string.**  So needs to be

```
this.ViewData["State"] = new SelectList(db.States.ToList(), "StateName", "StateName");
```

Then in your view

```
@Html.DropDownList("State")
```