# How to populate ListItem with records from sql table in MCV ViewModel

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am able to populate a ListItem for my ViewModel as given below:

```
    public IEnumerable<ListItem> AllTextEntries {
    get
    {
        var items = new List<ListItem>
            {
                new ListItem() {Id = 1, Name = "Text1"},
                new ListItem() {Id = 2, Name = "Text2"},
                new ListItem() {Id = 3, Name = "Text3"}
            };
        return items;
    }
}
```

But I dont know how to populate it from records from an sql database table.
DBContext and model for the table is established via entity-framework in my mvc-project.

Can anybody give me a hint how to populate the ListItem from records in an sql dadabase table?

Regards, Manu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC Drop Down list with entity framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663068/mvc-drop-down-list-with-entity-framework)

Comment: It works my solution ?

Comment: Alexandru's answer worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<ListItem> AllTextEntries {
    get
    {
        var items = new List<ListItem>();
        using(var context=new DBContext()){
             foreach(var item in context.listTable.ToList()){
                  items.Add(new ListItem(){Id=item.Id,Name=item.Name});
             }
        }
        return items;
    }
}
```