# How to populate a dropdownlist based on Id from a SQL Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, crud, viewbag

I am trying to create a drop down list in one of my CRUD screens that are based on a different model in my program. Right now it inputs the values based on ID but I want it to be able to populate the names of instructors in a drop-down list.

I've tried a few different things using the select list but it didn't seem to work.

This is my model:

```
     [Table("Section")]
    public class Section
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }


        [DisplayName("Section")]
        public int? section { get; set; }

        public Nullable <int> instructor_id { get; set; }
        public int location_id { get; set; }
        public int modality_id { get; set; }
        public int DOW_id { get; set; }
        public int course_id { get; set; }

        public virtual DOW DOW { get; set; }
        public virtual Instructor Instructor { get; set; }
        public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
        public virtual Modality Modality { get; set; }
        public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
```

This is my controller:

```
 // GET: Sections/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Sections/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,section,startTime,endTime,startDate,endDate,isTap,isActive,instructor_id,location_id,modality_id,DOW_id,course_id")] Section section)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Sections.Add(section);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            //ViewBag.instruct = new SelectList(db.Instructors, "Id", "lname", section.instructor_id);

            return View(section);
        }
```

And this is my view

```
  <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.instructor_id, "instructor_id" , htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.instructor_id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.instructor_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: kindly have a reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/26663526/7262120 of John Peters

Answer (score 0):

Taken form [John Peters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26663526/7262120) answers, kindly take a look

Create a data layer that retrieves a list of what you want. Then use EF to get all the states.

```
//assuming you have a table of states..
var states = db.States();
```

The states table should be a Unique list of states.

```
var selectList = new List<SelectListItem>(); 
foreach(var thing in states){
    //if you got everything, thus the ID field for the value...   
   selectList.Add(new SelectListItem {Text =thing.State, Selected = false, Value = thing.ID);
}
```

Make sure in your Viewmodel class that selectlist is a public property.....and set to what you did above. You also need to provided a string for the view selection post back.

```
StatesSelectList = selectList;
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StatesSelectList {get;set;}
public string SelectedState {get;set;}
```

In your view, do this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(p => Model.SelectedState, Model.StatesSelectList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the Get Method in Controller as follows:

```
// GET: Sections/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.Instructors = db.Instructors.ToList();

        return View();
    }
```

Your HTML need to be changed as follows:

```
 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.instructor_id, "instructor_id" , htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.instructor_id, new SelectList(ViewBag.Instructors, "Id", "Name"), new { @class = "form-control" } )
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.instructor_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Make sure field names are correct.