# Change in dropdownlist values does not return updated value to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm having trouble returning updated values from a DropDownList within a view to the controller. The DropDownList allows the users to change the value from "unscheduled to scheduled"

I'm returning a list of orders with an attribute named `status` (can either be "scheduled" or "unscheduled"). Currently all orders return status "unscheduled".

Below is the code for the DropDownList:

[image: Code for DropDownList]

[image: After changing the DDL values to yes and no respectively, code still returns original values]

After changing the DDL values to yes and no respectively, code still returns original values
[image]

action code for displaying

```
  public ActionResult reviewOrderCSVPost()
    {


        // display vieworder page with status (unscheduled)
        // return RedirectToAction("ViewOrders", new { status = "unscheduled" });


        var data = OrderProcessor.LoadOrder("unscheduled");

        List<Order> orders = new List<Order>();

        foreach (var row in data)
        {
            orders.Add(new Order
            {
                orderId = row.orderId,
                partId = row.partId,
                projectName = row.projectName,
                lastMaterialDate = row.lastMaterialDate,
                shipDate = row.shipDate,
                quantity = row.quantity,
                status = row.status,
                priority = row.priority
            });
        }

        //   OrderDetail ObjorderDetail = new OrderDetail();
        //  ObjorderDetail.OrderDetails = orders;

        return View(orders);
    }
```

Action code for Post request (status should change depending on user selection of dropdownlist)

```
  public ActionResult reviewOrderCSVSchedule( int[] orderId, string[] status)
    {
```

**EDIT**

Current plan, is to have a unique ddl by using "DDL_" +@item.orderId and unique hidden field named "hidden_"@item.orderId. I will place a on change method on the DDL and trigger a jquery function which will change the value of the hidden field value. Hope it works

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We love code in questions, but code as text and not as image ;-)

Comment: using console did you check the value of dropdown is changing?Also, its better to modify `item.status` to `modelItem.status`

Comment: im having a really bad day, I just found out a similar problem on my other methods. 
The Post request action takes in int[] Id in controller , however its having the same problem, does not change according to user selection!! 
e.g list contains
ID
1,2

user swap the sequence to 2,1. Post request int[] still returns 1,2

 if you are wondering how i capture the array of id. Im using   <input type="hidden" name="orderId" value=" @item.orderId" />

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are passing Status[] in controller action method. When you change dropdown, you need to bind the latest value in Status every time for scheduled and unscheduled. That might works in your case.

Comment: care to elaborate more? how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Could you take a look at this

[MVC Drop Down list with entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663068/mvc-drop-down-list-with-entity-framework/26676136#26676136)

Use `modelItem.status` as your 1st parameter in `DropDownListFor`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => modelItem.status, new SelectList(Model.SiteNames, "Value", "Text"))
```

`modelItem.status` should also be a `string` not `string[]`

If this doesn't help, please show your `Action` code and the way you are posting this data, whether submitting form with `type = submit` or an `ajax post`.

EDIT: Ok I think I see your problem now.

`@item.status` has the value "unscheduled" when the page loads, it then sets the value for the hidden element to "unscheduled" and never changes, since Razor code does not run client side. What you need is a unique id for hidden element, a pseudo class on your dropdownlist to identify it and some jquery to handle persisting the users selection.

So you will need something like this for your `hidden` element:

```
<input type="hidden" name="status" id=@item.Id value=@item.status />
```

and something like this for your `DropDownList`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => item.status, new SelectList(listItems, "Value", "Text"), new { @id=item.Id, @class=item.Id })
```

You can use some other unique property other than `item.Id`, just make sure you use the same property on both hidden and `DropDownListFor` as this will make your jquery much simpler.

```
$(function () {
    $('select[name="status"]').on('click', function () {
        var hiddenId = $(this).attr('class');
        var persistValue = $(this).val();
        $('#' + hiddenId).val(persistValue);
    });
});
```

This will allow you to add any number of `Orders` to the page and have each hidden's value properly bound to the value set for its respective `DropDownListFor`. You should also be able to use a `jquery change` event over `click` event.

Hope this helps in resolving this.

Comment: I am displaying the dropdown values fine. However I am having trouble with returning the individual status.
when i change any values in my dropdownlist , it just returns the original values

Comment: @TheBoredProgrammer Use modelItem.status as your 1st parameter in dropdownlistfor. I assume this is the property you are checking for the change.

Comment: I mention in my other answer exactly how to get the entire thing working. You may only need 1 part of the solution, but it's worth the read.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. item.status is correct because im using  foreach (var item in Model). if i use modelItem.status its produces a error stating that IEnumerable<order> does not contain definition for status...

Comment: Ok I see your problem is occuring on this line then

Comment: ok , so I can just bound them to e.g orderId which is unique to each row? the returned array should reflect user change? 

i tried and , its weird that console is giving me this warning that "Found 2 elements with non-unique id #item_status" the dropdownList.

btw im not adding any orders . the purpose of this page is to show a list<orders> with attribute = "unscheduled" , user can select on the DDL if they want to schedule this order or not. However, i just cant seem to get the "new DDL status" input at in my POST action for processing

Comment: @TheBoredProgrammer amended again, set a custom id for each dropdown `@id=item.Id`

Comment: Have edited, currently my hidden field and DDL are both using item.orderId , which is unique for each record. 

i tried to console.log , but i dont thing my code is running that JS function. probably because the JS is calling onclick event of the hidden field, which is never clicked?

Comment: The selector only applies the click event handler to a `select` element that has the `name="status"`. Have you included the javascript cdn?

Comment: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`, but you would've gotten an error in console that $ is not defined. Use the change event instead, but I don't think this would make a difference

Comment: add `alert("test")` above the event handler in the `$(function() {` function. If that doesn't show popup when screen loads, then you have a problem with your jquery on your page

Comment: yep , Jquery is not working. This could be the warning blocking the Jquery. "jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'methods' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'methods' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (https://localhost:44363/scripts/jquery.validate.date.js:2:17)" I created a jquery.validate.date JS file to override default jquery checks on date format. could this be the issue?

Comment: my Jquery :
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      
            alert("test");
         $(function () {
             $('select[name="status"]').on('click', function () {
                 console.log("test");
        var hiddenId = $(this).attr('class');
        var persistValue = $(this).val();
        $('#' + hiddenId).val(persistValue);
    });
});

Comment: @TheBoredProgrammer yes runtime errors in your js will stop execution of js that follows. Also, put the `alert("test")` inside  `$(function () {,` so like this `$(function () { alert("test");`

Comment: Once your js is working again the alert popup will show on page load

Comment: interesting , Its not the warning that is causing the error. tried alert on my other JS pages and it works! <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {



              alert("test");
            }); ~some other JS~ });this is weird. i will continue to look into it but my console has not errors on jquery issues but alert is not popping up

Comment: get rid of the `$(document).ready` and just call the `alert` function... what happens then? Sorry there isn't much to go on to actually assist you with this.

Comment: Hi , reporting back , have fixed the jquery , alert popup is working. weird , i removed my sweetalert.js code for the message popup and it works. Js code dont not activate on change.

Comment: Ok great, it should work with the `.click` event, can you mark the answer if it helped please

Comment: hmm , dosent work. i dont think this code will work   $('select[name="status"]').on('click', function () {
            alert("test");
            console.log("test");
            var hiddenId = $(this).attr('class');
            var persistValue = $(this).val();
            $('#' + hiddenId).val(persistValue);
        }); since this is calling the <input type=hidden> which is never "click". Im thinking of using a  $("body").on("click", "#btnSave", function () {
        thats activates on click of "submit" button and loop through the list of orders and using ajax to return the function.