# Creating dropdownlist from database with Entity Framework Core in an ASP.NET Core 5 MVC application

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

In my app I'm trying to populate a drop-down menu by taking data from the db with EF Core, but unfortunately I've been trying it for two days without success.

I have tried to do this as recommended in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663068/mvc-drop-down-list-with-entity-framework), but I keep getting errors.

More specifically the error I'm facing now is

> 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Years' and no accessible extension method 'Years' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found

This error comes from the view:

```
 @Html.DropDownList(m => m.Years, Model.Years, "-- Select year --")
```

Here is my model class:

```
public partial class Bdgfixmonth
{
    public int Counter { get; set; }
    public int Byear { get; set; }

    //
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Years { get; set; }

    public string Bbudget { get; set; }
    public int Bmonth { get; set; }
    public string Blongmonth { get; set; }
    public int Closed { get; set; }
    public string Current { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my controller for the `GET` action method `Index`:

```
private readonly salesContext _context;
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Years { get; set; }

public bdgfixmonthController(salesContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var bdgfixmonths = await _context.Bdgfixmonths.ToListAsync();

    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetAllYears()
    {
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> list = _context.Bdgfixmonths
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(s => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Selected = false,
                    Text = s.Byear.ToString(),
                    Value = s.Byear.ToString()
                });
            
        return list;
    }

    Years = GetAllYears();

    return View(bdgfixmonths);
}
```

The goal here is to populate the drop-down menu with the data of the db, and then make a query based on the selected value, so that only the relevant values are shown (in this case based on the year).

Any help would be very appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hello, I mean the newer .NET 5.

Comment: you also forgot to set your model's property: bdgfixmonths.Years = GetAllYears()

Comment: Yes sorry, I inlcuded the variable declaration now.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're returning a model that contains a list of `Bdgfixmonths`, it's probably better to create a view model that looks like this:

```
public class BdgfixmonthsViewModel
{
   public List<Bdgfixmonth> Bdgfixmonths { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Years { get; set; }
}
```

Then, your Action Method will change to:

```
private readonly salesContext _context;

public bdgfixmonthController(salesContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var vm = new BdgfixmonthsViewModel();
    var bdgfixmonths = await _context.Bdgfixmonths.ToListAsync();

    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetAllYears()
    {
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> list = _context.Bdgfixmonths
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(s => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Selected = false,
                    Text = s.Byear.ToString(),
                    Value = s.Byear.ToString()
                });
            
        return list;
    }

    vm.Years = GetAllYears();
    vm.Bdgfixmonths = bdgfixmonths; 

    return View(vm);
}
```

Your ViewModel will have the two collections which can then be used in the view.  You will need to update the View to reference the `Bdgfixmonth` properties like `Bdgfixmonths.Bbudget` for example. Also, the model will change to something like:

```
@model IEnumerable<Bdgfixmonth>
```

becomes

```
@model BdgfixmonthsViewModel
```

And then any iteration code will change to:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Bdgfixmonths)
    {
      item.Bbudget
    }
```

Comment: Years = GetAllYears();  does not work, the error message is " 'List<Bdgfixmonth>' does not contain a definition for 'Years' and no accessible extension method 'Years' accepting a first argument of type 'List<Bdgfixmonth>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). "

Comment: @chdev - my bad, just noticed you're returning a collection of `Bdgfixmonths`, I will alter my answer now.

Comment: Yes I did but as I am new I need a minimal reputation to have the upvotes I make show up.